# Use CSS from local file in WebView with React Native and Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, exponent, expo

I'm using the latest Expo SDK. I use a non-detached project.
I need to load a `css` from local file in a `WebView` that loads an `html` from string like this:

```
<WebView source={{ baseUrl: './', html: this.fullPost }} />
```

Where `this.fullPost` looks like this

```
this.fullPost = `
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>some html that uses style.css</body>
  </html>`;
```

So where should I put the `style.css` file and what should I specify as the `baseUrl`?
How should this with Expo?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to wrap your css code into a javascript file:

style.js:

```
const css = `
<style>
// copy your css file's content here
</style>
`;
export default css;
```

Then just `import style from './style';` and you can simply concat the `style` to `this.fullPost`.